# Add Custom Profile Field as Notes

Tags: custom-field

I would like to add a custom field "NOTES" to the user profile. This custom field should not only be updated,saved and display the current value but be displayed as ongoing (previous and current) notes on the user profile. For example:

1/1/2012 user xx wrote: Lorem ispum ispum
1/2/2012 user xx wrote: Lorem ispum ispum ispum
1/3/2012 user xx wrote: Lorem ispum ispum ispum ispum

All "Notes" that the user adds should be displayed on his profile.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: hi kaiser. thank you. I think I didnt have enough points to choose the right answer before. I tried a few times. Will get into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be easier to create a custom post type Notes, than on a user page just get all notes of a specific author and than display them. 
By creating a custom post type you may easily create a interface and all saving/handling functions.
If you would like to do it as a custom field in the user edit screen it would take a lot of work, and it would be just a waste of time cause currently custom post types are really great to customize.

Comment: Hi Jakub, thank you so much for your answer. You might be totally right. I have to think how I am going to implement that since the user only has access to the front end interface.